# image out of bounds of image view

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble figuring out why my image isn't within the bounds of my imageview.  Instead, it is floating off to the left and hidden.  Is this only because the Graphical Interface doesn't show it?

EDIT:

I edited the original code to more clearly show the issue i'm having and added a picture(i want the image to show in the red box):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/top_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"     
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="195"
            android:background="#00FF00"/>  
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:src="@drawable/img" />   

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000FF"
        />  
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have it working. The height attribute of "block_container" is set to a random 200dp you WILL want to change the height to whatever your needs are, or potentially set it to "wrap_content". I tested this on emulator and device.

I am also assuming that you want all three block to be equally spaced. Notice how the parent "block_container" has a weight_sum of 9? Well the children are equal widths because they have a weight of 3 each (3 blocks * 3 weight each = 9 weight total).

I noticed before it looks like you were trying to use weight as width directly e.g. a weight of 569. Just remember weight != width directly.

EDIT: added the missing id attributes from some of the views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/block_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="9"
        >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/left_block"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#00FF00"/>  
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />   

        <View
            android:id="@+id/right_block"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#0000FF"
        />  
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting `android:layout_height` to be 0dp?  I can't even get it to display unless I change this to something like `fill_parent`.

Either way, its because of your `layout_weight` for the parent `LinearLayout`.  Specify a larger `layout_weight` for your `ImageView` and it will come into view.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_img"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="279"
        android:src="@drawable/my_img" />
```

This worked for me.. but math might not be right.

Comment: i updated the question a bit.  maybe i'm not understanding something?  wh do i need to increase the weight. shouldn't the image be in bounds?

Comment: Did you even try? I replicated the problem and solved it by increasing the weight of the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to begin with the issues with what you posted, some simple observations before even debugging further:

- Your layouts ALL need ids (e.g. android:id="@+id/another_layout")
- You have a width on the second linear layout of 0dp
- Your first linear layout has a height of 0 dp, combined with the previous I'm surprised it renders at all
- The last inner linear layout again has a width of 0dp

What are you trying to achieve? To me there seems to be a lot of layouts unless you have removed some elements to make it easier to understand? You could post a simple image of what you are trying to do then perhaps we can help you refine the markup?

Comment: added a picture and edited the code to give you a better idea.  i added 0dp because i'm trying to use weight to specift the height and width

Comment: I agree with Graham Smith.. there seems to be a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.